# Inputting Layers in QGIS for PyWPS Processes

Tags: qgis, pywps

I recently downloaded the PyWPS demo files from github here: https://github.com/PyWPS/pywps-4-demo. I'm having some trouble figuring out how to use some of the processes. In particular, processes like "feature_count" require the user to input a "layer". What should be entered in the text box for the process to get my GML layer in QGIS?
[image]

Comment: Hello, it has been a few years, but did you actually manage to solve this? I have the very same issue, and i find the docs, both from pywps and the qgispluing, to be rather unhelpful.