# Handling complex input in the QGIS wps client

Tags: python, qgis-3, wps, pywps

I'm trying to get the [qgis-wps-client](https://github.com/sourcepole/qgis-wps-client) to process complex inputs such as a gml or any type of file. I have a working instance of the [pywps-flask-demo](https://github.com/geopython/pywps-flask). For simple inputs like strings or numbers this works perfectly fine.

Server side code looks like this:

```py
from pywps import Process, LiteralOutput, ComplexInput, Format
from .pgm import PGManager as pgm #self implemented class for database stuff

class StrToCoords(Process):
    def __init__(self):
        # self.pgm = pgm()

        inputs = [ComplexInput('text/plain', 'Input file',
                               [Format('text/plain', extension='.txt')])]
        outputs = [LiteralOutput('response_data',
                                 'Output response', data_type='string')]

        super(StrToCoords, self).__init__(
            self._handler,
            identifier='upload',
            title='Fileupload process',
            abstract='Upload a file, with strings to be processed',
            version='1.3.3.7',
            inputs=inputs,
            outputs=outputs,
            store_supported=True,
            status_supported=True
        )

    def _handler(self, request, response):
        # do DB magic...
        # not yet implemented
        return result
```

The wps client, reads the process definition and generates it's ui, which for me results in this:
[image: wps client ui screenshot]

I can not figure out what the expected input in this is. I have tried : raw strings, a path to a file, the contents of a GML, GeoJSON. I get a key error from inside the plugin. I also tried the sample services from the wps package and they are not compatible either.

Sadly neither the wps, no the wps client docs seem to have a valid example of this usecase.

Has anyone managed to make this work? There are some questions here relating to this topic, but they are very old and do not answer this topic. E.G:

[Inputting Layers in QGIS for PyWPS Processes](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/193081/inputting-layers-in-qgis-for-pywps-processes#comment658996_193081)

[qgis wps client mime type not supported](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/244173/qgis-wps-client-mime-type-not-supported/244204#244204)

In the greater scheme of things, what i am trying to accomplish is, make some logic implemented on a PostGIS database available for QGIS users through the wps. The intended workflow is, for the user to input a batch of information which gets pasend into the database, processed and the results returned.

Comment: I'd suggest you to ask directly at QGIS web client issues: https://github.com/sourcepole/qgis-wps-client/issues Perhaps you can get an answer from the devs themselves.